# How can I build a 2 level bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar, justinmind

I want to reproduce something like this in bootsrap:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/1BjGYgZ]

I wonder if u can help me or if you know any plugin that can work. This one is made in justinmind.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: To vague. What you want to produce an entire site like the provided link? Or just a segment of the site?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many actual Bootstrap tutorials online that you can start with.

Comment: I want 2 navbars one above the other and when i scroll down the top navbar desapears and bottom sticks in the top. the logo also changes from big to small

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials online on how to make a Bootstrap navbar so I won't go into that, but in order to get two things on top of each other on only one side of the page, you need to do something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.inner-right-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner-right-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">LEFT DIV</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="inner-right-1">TOP</div>
    <div class="inner-right-2">BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are two main divs (left and right), which each take up `x` amount of space on the page. Inside one of the divs, place two inner divs with one on top of the other. These divs would each contain a navbar, in your case.